# R cleaning up a column

Tags: r

I have - from my perspective - quite a tricky task: I have a large dataset about VW cars. One column contains the car models. I only would like to have there VW + mode (e.g. VW Golf or VW Passat). I could delete all the stuff I don't need with `gsub`, but that is not efficient in my eyes and would need probably 50 lines of code.

What would be an easy and efficent way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of your data frame, use `dput(head(data,10))` so we can cut and paste the data into the console. Also, show us what the desired output data looks like.

Comment: How about `gusb`bing  against [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Volkswagen_passenger_cars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you have tried with `gsub`, But I would do something like this:

```
gsub('(^VW \\w+).*','\\1',modell)
```

Using some data :

```
modell <- c('VW Caddy Life 1.6 ',
'VW Passat 3.2',
'VW Bora 2.8',
'VW Golf 1.4',            
'VW Passat (Kombi)')

gsub('(^VW \\w+).*','\\1',modell)
[1] "VW Caddy"  "VW Passat" "VW Bora"   "VW Golf"   "VW Passat"
```

Comment: Could you shortly explain what all the symbols in your gsub solution do? Just that I learn something and can reuse it later. I looked in gsub help but didn't get a full picture. Thx.